# RegEx for replacing abc_def with abcDef entire word avoiding R.id.abc_def

Tags: regex

I'm trying to migrate from Kotiln synthetics to DataBinding.

So I'm trying to replace stuff like `input_layout_phone_number` with `binding.inputLayoutPhoneNumber`.

I got the part with replacing `input_layout_phone_number` with `inputLayoutPhoneNumber`, but I can only replace each underscore alone.

Also, something like `R.string.abc_def` gets included under this RegEx I'm using, also `KEY_ABC`

Find : `_(w)`

Replace : `\U$1`

Any idea how I can replace the entire word, and only find the words that do not have a `.` before them? Maybe also replace the entire word at once

Example :

```
input_text_field_layout
R.id.input_text_field_layout
TEXT_FIELD_LAYOUT
```

Expected output :

```
inputTextFieldLayout
R.id.input_text_field_layout
TEXT_FIELD_LAYOUT
```

Preferred output :

```
binding.inputTextFieldLayout
R.id.input_text_field_layout
TEXT_FIELD_LAYOUT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Android Studio**, you can use

```php
(\G(?!^)[^\W_]*|\b(?<!\.)(?![A-Z_]+\b)[^\W_]+)_([^\W_])
```

Replace with `$1\U$2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GeplFW/3).

*Details*:

- `(\G(?!^)[^\W_]*|\b(?<!\.)(?![A-Z_]+\b)[^\W_]+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): either the end of the previous successful match and then any zero or more word chars other than `_` or a word boundary not immediately preceded with a `.` char, and then one or more word chars other than an underscore (with the exception of words only consisting of ALLCAPS letters and underscores, see `(?![A-Z_]+\b)` negative lookahead)
- `_` - an underscore
- `([^\W_])` - Group 2: a word char minus `_`

In **Visual Studio Code**, you can use

```
(?<=\b(?<!\.)(?=[a-z_]+\b)\w+)_([^\W_])
```

Replace with `\U$1`. Make sure the `Aa` option (Match case) is ON.

*Details*:

- `(?<=\b(?<!\.)(?=[a-z_]+\b)\w+)` -  a location that is immediately preceded with a word boundary and one or more word chars that are not immediately preceded with a dot (but the word must consist of lowercase letters or/and underscores)
- `_` - an underscore
- `([^\W_])` - Group 1: a word char other than a `_`.

DEMO:

[image]

Comment: Android Studio says it's a bad pattern. Same with Visual Studio Code

Comment: @A-AndroidUCG I thought you were doing it in Notepad++. Now, it will work in Android Studio.

Comment: KEY_ABC is getting replaced too, which I don't want to replace

Comment: @A-AndroidUCG What is the rule here? ALLCAPS word? Then use `(\G(?!^)[^\W_]*|\b(?<!\.)(?![A-Z_]+\b)[^\W_]+)_([^\W_])`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GeplFW/3).

Comment: an all non-caps word. All the characters are not caps

Comment: @A-AndroidUCG Aha, so all letters must be small? Replace `(?![A-Z_]+\b)`  with `(?=[a-z_]+\b)` / `(?=[\p{Ll}_]+\b)`

Comment: In the Android Studio one, some of them are being ignored `radio_button_domain_default_name_servers`

Comment: @A-AndroidUCG Please think about the rules again and formulate them clearly and definitively, update the question with a comprehensive set of test cases. See [the latest regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GeplFW/5).

Comment: @A-AndroidUCG If you have trouble with the current solution and you still need help,  you should share a test case stating your input text and expected output.

Comment: I added an example, hopefully it'l help

Comment: @A-AndroidUCG [It works for me](https://regex101.com/r/GeplFW/6). Also, you cannot add `binding.` as prefix because you are using multiple matches to replace parts of the same word. You can only add `bindings.` later, as the second step, [like this](https://regex101.com/r/GeplFW/7).

Comment: Neither of those work, on either of the IDEs

Comment: @A-AndroidUCG You probably do not turn on `Match case` option. I updated the VSCode answer part.